# Does Spring XD supports in-memory processing in Hadoop

Tags: spring, hadoop, apache-spark, spring-xd, geode

In SpringXD site 
 [link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-xd/)

> Features
>
> Data from anywhere, to anywhere
>
> Data-driven apps require refined and consolidated data at scale.
>   Spring XD’s stream and batch workflow lets you build pipelines to
>   consume data from various endpoints and consolidate them in Hadoop,
>   in-memory data grids such as Redis or GemFire, and virtually any data
>   store.

Comment: What do you mean by in-memory processing in Hadoop? You want a HDFS to run in memory?

Answer (score 0):

SpringXD is the data ingestion layer.  If you want to do you want to use SpringXD to sink your data into Gemfire,Redis, or JBDC and do your in memory processing there, SpringXD gives you tools out of the box to do so.  For example you could use SpringXD to mine the TwitterStream, take all those tweets and sink them into Gemfire where you would then do processing.  SpringXD is meant to be the ingestion layer as opposed to the computation layer.